# Php / MySQL Insert record query error?

Tags: php, mysql, function, insert

I have a file called database.php which contains the following:

```
    <?php

// Database connectivity stuff

$host     = "localhost"; // Hostname for the database. Usually localhost
$username = "root"; // Username used to connect to the database
$password = "root"; // Password for the username used to connect to the database
$database = "blog"; // The database used

// Connect to the database using mysqli_connect
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

// Check the connection for errors
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection)) {
    // Stop the whole page from loading if errors occur
    die("<br />Could not connect to the database. Please check the settings and try again.") . mysqli_connect_error() . mysqli_connect_errno();
}


?>
```

I have a new file called functions.php which contains the following:

```
<?php

// Functions file for the system

function add_post($user_id, $body) {
    $post = "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, body, stamp) VALUES ($user_id, $body, now())";
    $insert_post = "mysqli_query($connection, $post)";
}

?>
```

And an insert post php page (newPost.php) which contains the following:

```
<?php

// Define the user id and get the post from the form
$user_id = 1; // User ID hard coded for testing purposes
$body = substr($_POST['body'],0,200);

// Insert the post in the database using the add_post() function

if (isset($user_id, $body) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) {

    // Insert the post in the database if conditions were met
    add_post($user_id, $body);
    }
    // If the conditions were not met, display an error
    else {
        die("The post was not added. Something went wrong. Please try again later");
    }
?>
```

When I try to post some text I get the following error:

**Notice: Undefined variable: connection in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/includes/functions.php on line 7**

What am I doing wrong here? isn't $connection supposed to be passed as i used require(); in my newPost.php file?

Answer (score 6):

This is totally wrong:

```
$insert_post = "mysqli_query($connection, $post)";
               ^---                             ^--
```

You're not executing your query. You're defining a string which happens to contain some text that **LOOKS** like a query call. Remove the quotes...

Comment: Right now this too. It was passed as a string. Now it just shows a blank page after i removed the quotes

Answer (score 2):

It's a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. `$connection` is not available to `add_post()` unless you pass it as a parameter:

```
function add_post($user_id, $body, $connection) {
    $post = "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, body, stamp) VALUES ($user_id, $body, now())";
    $insert_post = mysqli_query($connection, $post);
}
```

You can also use the `global` keyword but that is generally considered a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it kinda makes sense. Now I get the following error:

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/includes/functions.php on line 7**

Comment: See Marc's answer below for that solution

Comment: Thanks John. I fixed that too and now it just shows up as a blank page when I submit the form, and it doesn't insert any records.

Comment: Are you sure you have error handling everywhere and that execution isn't ending before you can output an error message?

Answer (score 1):

The above answers should get it to work for you, however consider using mysqli prepared statements instead of mysqli_query. Prepared statements are safer and protect you from sql injection through user input.

Comment: That is correct. I just want to get things going first, and go over them again to cover the security issues. I know it's like scratching on the left ear with the right hand, but it makes more sense to me like this.

Comment: Fair enough, just making sure ;)